# What would Religion that worshipped humans be like with alien followers and why would they do so

Tags: aliens, religion

I'm writing a story with aliens from another planet worshipping humans on earth and wanted to know why would a alien species of spider-like humanoids do that.
Especially since humans aren't that good and they have a major religion.

Comment: Too broad. This site isn't meant to brainstorm for you, but help you when you hit a wall in the middle of your own work.

Comment: Not all gods are supposed to be good.

Comment: Being power wise and come from the heavens. That's enough to be considered a god in a number of religions.

Comment: If there religion is polytheistic it should be easy for them to incorporate humans as minor gods polytheistic religions did this all the time.

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding. Per the [help/on-topic], we help you build your world, not tell your story. This is 100% story based (VTC:Too Story-Based). This Q is also open-ended, allows all answers to have equal value, is hypothetical (what's the psychology, demographics, philosophies, etc. of your aliens?), all of which are forbidden in the [help/dont-ask] (VTC:Opinion-Based). If you read the [help/on-topic], you'll discover we discourage brainstorming questions. They violate SE's rules too often.

Answer (score 1):

Gods don't have to be good.

If you look at say the Greek Myths - the purpose of the stories about the Gods is to teach a lesson about Humanity - the cost of Hubris, The wisdom of Mercy, what happens when Zeus can't keep it in his pants...

We tend to think of Gods being perfect in the west, but this is more due to the Abrahamic religions and I daresay there's a lot of room for interpretation - for example the destruction of Sodom and Gamorrah could be up for debate, same with Jesus and the money-lenders in the Temple.

If you consider Religious stories to be Morality tales - either demonstrating the potential pitfalls of the wrong decisions, or showing what a virtuous decision looks like.

In terms of what the Religion would look like - you can have a lot of fun here - and as people have pointed out - this is so broad as to breach the rules for a good question - however the second part - the Why is probably more interesting:

Most religions, once you abstract out all the supernatural stuff - the main function of most religions is to teach the individual how to live a good and productive life *and give them hope and strength to ward off the trials of life*.

For example - consider the Jewish prohibition against eating Shellfish - seems rather silly - but if you think about a tribal desert society, that eats from a shared food bowl/source and limited access to water - then a round of Shellfish food poisoning where *everyone* starts squirting at both ends, could quickly lead to the elders of the tribe and the children of the tribe getting so dehydrated that they die.

Suddenly, in a historical and cultural context, such a rule doesn't seem so silly.

Therefore - to answer your question, you have to ask *what is it that Humans do, that Spider aliens don't do - which leads to a better society*

And if we assume your spider aliens are similar enough to Earth spiders - I think I can answer that question:

**Nurturing Parents**

Humans, for all their faults, on average, are pretty damn good at raising their children. Even the worst parent (that isn't breaking any laws) is still better than 99.999% of animal parents.

So the Spider Aliens see this behavior in humans and go 'Wait, what?!?' and so form a cult around Humans as to how they raise their children and use this as a Moral guide that they believe in to teach them how to parent their children and become a better society.

Answer (score -1):

1. Most gods aren't suposed to be morally good,look up any non-Abrahamic religions.
2. If their religion is polytheistic then they should have no problem accepting and incorporating humans as minor deities. Polytheism did this all the time.
3. Many religions worship gods because they created humanity. If Humans created the spiders and so they view as worthy of worship.
4. Other gods are worshipped for there power. If Humans are more advanced then the spiders then they may be considered wise and powerful and therefore worthy of worship.
5. If the human come from space they they will literally be coming to the planet from the heavens. That enough to qualify you as a god in a number of religions.
6. Human reward spiders that worship them with boons greatly encourage the practice.

Comment: If, if, if, if, if.... AKA, VTC:Needs Details or VTC:Too Story-Based.

Comment: Why you getting upset at me talk to the original creator of the post.

Comment: sorry it was just my first post

Comment: Why get upset with the person who answered an unprepared post when the Help Center directs us to only answer well-asked questions? I'm reasonably sure the OP didn't hold a gun to your head and force you to answer.

Comment: Again my mistake, you don't have to comment if you don't want to.

Comment: @JBH I get to decide what I think is a unprepared question and what I think is not mind your own business.

Comment: @BryanMcClure The reason the "Flag" link exists on answers is because, no, you are not allowed to make that decision on your own. Answers, like questions, are also community moderated.

Comment: @JBH and you are not the community.

Comment: I'm a member of the community, @BryanMcClure. Please remember that you are expected to [answer well-asked questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). At 20K you should know that.

Comment: @JBH exactly your are just a member and can not speak for the hole community. As a member also I can decide what answers I consider to be "well asked" without interference from you. Thank very much.

Comment: @BryanMcClure The point of community moderation is to help us all remember the rules created by Stack Exchange, like the rule obligating us to only answer well-asked questions and to help OPs to write well-asked questions. This discussion is idiotic. You made a mistake. Rather than helping the OP write a good question you made four decisions on their behalf (Needs More Details) that are nothing more than a story-based rationalization (Too Story-Based). Next time I won't bother trying to help you write a better answer. I'll just flag it as low quality and move on.

Comment: @JBH You do that expect the same treatment.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Get off your angry high horse and *help moderate the site according to Stack Exchange's rules and our policies.* Remember that this all started because you wrote a lousy answer and I pointed it out *without flagging the answer.* You're welcome! It's as much your job to learn the rules and help moderate as it is mine and everybody else's. Do I want to close questions? No! Do I want to flag questions? No! But those are the tools SE gave us to remind people that *we have rules.* Learn them. Obey them. Help moderate. Cheers.

Comment: @JBH the only one on a high horse is you. All I want is you to mind your own business.  And why are you picking on me? There are 2 answers on this question.

Comment: I down-voted Demon's answer, but at least he took the time to explain his choices and took the time to explain some worldbuilding procedures - you didn't even do that. This answer is nothing but "mindless social fun" (see [help/dont-ask]). That's why you got a comment and he didn't.

Comment: @JBH Now your just making things up I did explain all my choices. And where exactly is it a rule that ever answer must explain world building procedures?

Comment: @BryanMcClure I didn't say that was a rule. I explained why I didn't leave Demon a comment. And you didn't explain your choices i.e., you didn't refer to anything that rationalized them. You just said, "if we do this..." which is putting words in the OP's mouth at best and storybuilding at worst. Compare Demon's first point vs. yours before SCL improved it. Neither answer is great, but yours is simply too brief with few references.

Comment: @JBH Are you blind ? Did you even read it?

Comment: @JBH I literally broke my answer down into points and explanations. can you not read what point did I raise that doesn't have a explanation?